# in Objective-C, how to access private property from category

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to access private property of a class from its category.

But to access private property, I have to redeclare the same private property in category.
If I don't redeclare, I get a compile error, `Property '<property name>' not found on object of type '<class name> *'`.

Is this correct way to access private property of class from category?
And are there better ways to do this?

The following code is the code which private property is redeclared in category:

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
-(void)method1;
@end
```

ClassA.m

```
#import "ClassA.h"

// private property
@interface ClassA()
@property (nonatomic) NSString *s;
@end

@implementation ClassA
@synthesize s;

-(void)method1
{
    self.s = @"a";
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - method1", self.s]);
}
@end
```

ClassA+Category.h

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@interface ClassA(Category)
-(void)method2;
@end
```

ClassA+Category.m

```
#import "ClassA+Category.h"

// redeclare private property
@interface ClassA()
@property(nonatomic) NSString *s;
@end

@implementation ClassA(Category)

-(void)method2
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - method2", self.s]);
}
@end
```

Is is good way to create a file(ClassA+Private.m) for private property and import it from ClassA.m and ClassA+Category.m:

ClassA+Private.m

```
@interface ClassA()
@property(nonatomic) NSString *s;
@end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to create `ClassA+Private.h` and import it in `ClassA.m` and `Category.m`. Mind the `h` at the end, you only need to declare your private properties and methods there, the definition is better kept in `ClassA.m`.

Comment: I'd say it would be better to import `ClassA+Private.h` in the `.m` only. Placing `ClassA+Private.h` in `ClassA.h` makes the properties visible to all classes that import `ClassA.h` which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Also, I think `ClassA+Protected.h` would be more accurate than `ClassA+Private.h`.

Comment: Agreed with 1 and edited the answer. As for protected, I agree this makes eyes bleed but for people not coming from other programming languages this probably doesn't make any difference, so I just used the naming suggested by author of the question.

Comment: It think some time has passed and it's fair to say 'Private' is now more of a convention.

Comment: @lawicko ClassA+Private.h in a separate file ?

Comment: @TheiCoder Yes, otherwise you keep everything in one header and wherever you import it your private interface will be visible.