# Access private properties and methods between class extension categories in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I have a class that I want to split across multiple files. I tried using categories, but can't figure out how to make it work.

My class is named `UserManager` and I want to create `UserManager+Amazon` and `UserManager+Facebook`.

The problem is that I **do need** to access private properties and/or methods in `UserManager+Amazon` that are implemented in `UserManager+Facebook`, and vice-versa.

How can I extract methods outside the main `UserManager.m` file, while maintaining the access to private stuff?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556134/in-objective-c-how-to-access-private-property-from-category

Comment: @Avi, But then, I get warnings that those methods are not implemented, right?

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment because it's wasn't all that coherent.  See my comment to the answer by CJ Dev.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: @Avi has an excellent idea below, although I have not tested it.

I have also just discovered a solution: [Properties for Class and Its Subclasses Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264263/properties-for-class-and-its-subclasses-only)

It works with categories and subclasses. I have tested it with my code and it works. It uses a class extension on the `BaseClass.h`, complete with an implemented example immediately below the accepted answer.

---

**OLD:**
*I've been struggling with this recently as well.
My current idea is to create a third category `UserManager+Private` that implements all of the private methods and handles the properties via associated objects (http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/).
It feels very unwieldy, but it might work for you. I would still be interested in a better solution if one exists.*

Comment: Instead of using associated objects, place these properties into the main class implementation.  Declare them in a private interface that your categories import.  The implementation of a category method (or property) has to exist in the class somewhere at compile time.  It doesn't have to exist in the `@implementation` section which is paired with the `@interface` that declares it.

Comment: @Avi, But the warnings are still produced, right? And I hate warnings. A simple `.h` and `.m` files demo implementation would help to visualize this solution.

Comment: No warnings are produced.  I do this myself to define aspect-specific interfaces for `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Comment: @CJDev, but if the `BaseClass.m` doesn't implement the `- (void)baz` method, a warning is generated, even if it is implemented in `ChildClass.m`. And in my case, I have a lot of methods that are not implemented in the base class, and I don't want to write empty methods in it.